# Do I empower a spell after or before I cast it?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

I wanted to know if I (as a sorcerer with empower spell metamagic) have to say that I'm empowering a spell before I cast it, or can I see the damage roll and then say I'm empowering it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can wait until you see the damage roll to Empower the spell. Empower Spell says:

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can spend 1
>   sorcery point to reroll a number of the damage dice up
>   to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). You must
>   use the new rolls.
>
> You can use Empowered Spell even if you have
>   already used a different Metamagic option during the
>   casting of the spell.

Every *other* metamagic option has to be used when you cast the spell, meaning that you have to decide to use them before you see the results. Empower Spell, on the other hand, is used when you roll the damage, and it's used to change the rolls you get for the damage.

Comment: Does "When you roll damage for a spell" not imply you have to spend it as you roll, not after?

Comment: @Protonflux By that logic, you would have to reroll the dice as you roll them, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.