# When do I state that I want to use empowered spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, sorcerer, metamagic

A sorcerer's metamagic option *Empowered Spell* states (emphasis mine):

> EMPOWERED SPELL
>   **When you roll damage** for a spell, you can spend 1
>   sorcery point to reroll a number of the damage dice up
>   to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). You must
>   use the new rolls.
>   You can use Empowered Spell even if you have
>   already used a different Metamagic option during the
>   casting of the spell.

Do I have to announce that I want to use this metamagic *before* I roll damage, or after I've seen my rolls? The latter would be preferable, obviously, but the phrasing isn't 100% clear (at least I don't think it is, but then again I'm not a native English speaker).

Note that this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64111/do-i-empower-a-spell-after-or-before-i-cast-it), which is about before/after the *casting*, while I'm asking about before/after *rolling*. Comments to its answer relate to this question, but don't solve it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You choose to do this after you have rolled the damage.  Note that it says "you can spend 1 sorcery point to *reroll* a number of the damage dice ..."  To be able to *reroll* dice, you must have already rolled them.

Comment: This. Logic of language dictates it, and Jeremy Crawford has basically said plain meaning of and logic of language should be followed when something isn't completely clear.